# Is there something tangible remaining from the Library of Alexandria?

Tags: ancient-egypt

From the fire and acts of desctruction on Library of Alexandria, is there remaining something? Did some tangible material, books, documents have been moved before the event or survived?

Comment: Thanks @SteveBird for the feedback, I just edited the question with more explicit term. Like SteveBird said, I was mainly looking for documents or books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course there is a chance that something had been at the Library of Alexandria at some point of time before it was destroyed (several times, actually).

But how would we know? Unless we find something written *alongside* the document in question that *states* said document had *been* at the Library before.

Which is hugely unlikely. Even today's libraries don't keep records right alongside the books, and I don't think at that point of time anyone kept record where a document *had been*.

So, do such legacies exist? [**Possible, even likely.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_of_Alexandria#Legacy) Do we know about it? **No**, not to my knowledge.